# Javascript file in conflict with other javascript

Tags: javascript

I think my javascript in my php file is in conflict with my javascript file.
I have a script that checks of the image is smaller then 2MB and a script that shows the image you selected in a small version. But the second part does not work when the first script is active. how do I fix this?

**script in HTML**

```
<script> 
window.onload = function() {
    var uploadField = document.getElementById("frontImages");
    uploadField.onchange = function() {
        if(this.files[0].size > 2000000){
        alert("File is too big!");
        this.value = "";
        };
    };
    var uploadField = document.getElementById("itemImages");

    uploadField.onchange = function() {
        if(this.files[0].size > 200){
        alert("File is too big!");
        this.value = "";
        };
    };
}
</script>
```

**.js file**

```
$("#frontImages").change(function () {
if ($('#frontImages').get(0).files.length > 0) {
    $('#frontImages').css('background-color', '#5cb85c');
} else {
    $('#frontImages').css('background-color', '#d9534f');
}
});

$("#itemImages").change(function () {
if ($('#itemImages').get(0).files.length > 0) {
    $('#itemImages').css('background-color', '#5cb85c');
} else {
    $('#itemImages').css('background-color', '#d9534f');
}
});

document.getElementById("frontImages").onchange = function () {
var x = document.getElementById('previewFrontImage');
x.style.display = 'block';
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    document.getElementById("previewFrontImage").src = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};

function previewImages() {
var $preview = $('#previewItemImages').empty();
if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);

function readAndPreview(i, file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    $(reader).on("load", function () {
        $preview.append($("<img/>", {src: this.result, height: 100}));
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

}

$('#itemImages').on("change", previewImages);
```

I'm guessing that the conflict is between the html script and this

```
document.getElementById("frontImages").onchange = function ()
```

I also have a question how I can fix that there will be no small image when the image is too big

Comment: may be you can check https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp

Comment: does not work but im pretty bad with javascript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct, `onchange` is simply member variable of various elements, and thus

```
var uploadField = document.getElementById("frontImages");
uploadField.onchange = function() {
```

and

```
document.getElementById("frontImages").onchange = function ()
```

are setting this single variable (of `frontImages`), which will store one callback function at a time.

You could use [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead, which maintains a list of event listeners, so there can be more than one. Modifying the lines to

```
var uploadField = document.getElementById("frontImages");
uploadField.addEventListener("change", function() {
```

and

```
document.getElementById("frontImages").addEventListener("change", function ()
```

will register both event listeners on `frontImages`, regardless of the order they are executed.

Side remark: when you have "nice" `id`s, `document.getElementById()` can be omitted, as elements with `id`s become variables (of `window` which is the global scope), and thus you could write `frontImages.addEventListener(...)`. You still need the getter in various cases, like when a local variable shadows the `id`, or when it is not usable as variable identifier (like `id="my-favourite-id"` or `id="Hello World"`)